# Correct nomenclature: Hamilton path, Hamilton's path or Hamiltonian path?

Tags: hamiltonian-path

What is the correct way?
Hamilton path, Hamilton's path or Hamiltonian path?
To be clear, I am referring to the correct way to name a graph such that there exists a single path (without repeated vertices) through all the vertices.

In Wikipedia it says "Hamiltonian path", whereas in an article I found "Hamilton path".

Comment: I think you see all three used. I personally prefer "Hamiltonian path" for no specific reason. Pick a term, define it, and stick to it in your writing.

Comment: I have never seen Hamilton's path. The other two forms I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen both Hamilton path (or Hamilton cycle) and Hamiltonian path (or Hamiltonian cycle). A graph, however, is always Hamiltonian (if it contains a Hamilton/Hamiltonian cycle). Consider for example the titles of two papers: *Hamiltonian cycles in random regular graphs* (Fenner & Frieze) and *Generating and counting Hamilton cycles in random regular graphs* (Frieze, Jerrum, Molloy, Robinson & Wormald). Alan Frieze apparently doesn't care too strongly about the issue.

However, I've never seen Hamilton's path or cycle.